# Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I am writing a simple tab view using fragment tab ( because TabActivity is being deprecated )

But when I try to run it, it alerts error "Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?". Also I am noticed that ActivityGroup and setup(void) are being deprecated too.

how can it be fixed?

```
public class ListTab extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_tab);

        FragmentTabHost listTab = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.list_tab_host);

        listTab.setup(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        TabSpec allPostSpec = listTab.newTabSpec("all_post");
        allPostSpec.setIndicator("All");
        Intent allPostIntent = new Intent(this,ListPost.class);
        allPostSpec.setContent(allPostIntent);

        listTab.addTab(allPostSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do not use TabSpec with Intent if you are using FragmentTabHost ... use this `addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)` version of addTab (remeber that clss should be the class which extends Fragment)

Comment: I change it to:
listTab.addTab(listTab.newTabSpec("all_post").setIndicator("All"), ListPost.class, null);
where ListPost is extends ListFragment

but the error is still the same :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using FragmentTabHost class with addTab(TabSpec, FragmentClass, Bundle)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
     mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
     mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
     mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
     FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
     mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                     LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
     mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                     LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
     mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                     LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
}
```

Where R.id.realtabcontent is your container.

You can found an example here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: Please paste the relevant portion of the link in the answer. If the link changes then future people might not be able to find it.

Comment: Ok ok, fixed, sorry, first post.